# Set an @Value property for an @Import spring config in a unit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

How do I set an `@Value` property for a context which I `@Import` into my unit test?

For example:

```
@Configuration
public void DatabaseTestsConfiguration
{
  @Value("${test.generateddl:true}")
  private boolean generateDdl;

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter()
  {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql( false );
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl( generateDdl );
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase( Database.H2 );
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
  }

   // Some more @Bean's here
}
```

In my unit test:

```
@Test
@ContextConfiguration
public void SomeTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests
{

  @Configuration
  @Import(DatabaseTestsConfiguration.class)
  public static class TestConfiguration
  {
  }
}
```

How do I now override the property `test.generateddl` to be `false` in my unit test? Note that I want to have it only for this unit test, so specifying something on the command line is a no-go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html#properties--

Example from spring [docu](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-spring):

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "timezone = GMT", "port: 4242" })
```